# How to convert from GMT to EST Timezone

Tags: xml, powershell, datetime

```
$url = "http://feeds.marketwatch.com/marketwatch/marketpulse"
[xml]$xml = (new-object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString($url)
$xml.rss.channel | Foreach {$_.item}  | Format-Table pubdate, title
```

I have successfully parsed the XML into a clean table.
[image]
How do I convert the datetime to EST from GMT?

Any help would be appreciated.  Thank you for your time.

Comment: You do not convert.  DateTime object is stored as GMT and using timezone is automatically display in local time.  XML is a string so make sure when you import the date it should include the timezone.  Then when you output is should automatically get displayed in local time.

Comment: you can use `[System.TimeZoneInfo]::ConvertTimeBySystemTimeZoneId(...)` method but you need to provide a sample of the data you have

Comment: Updated Question to provide a sample.

Comment: $url = "http://feeds.marketwatch.com/marketwatch/marketpulse"
[xml]$xml = (new-object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString($url)
$xml.rss.channel | Foreach {$_.item} | select @{N="pubdate";E={[System.TimeZoneInfo]::ConvertTimeBySystemTimeZoneId([datetime]$_.pubdate, 'Eastern Standard Time').ToString("ddd MMM d HH:mm:ss")}},title

Answer (score 2):

Cast to `Datetime`, use a [Calculated property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_calculated_properties?view=powershell-7.3) and format it as needed, see example for `MM/dd/yyyy`, see [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tostring?view=net-6.0#system-datetime-tostring(system-string)) for more information

```
$xml.rss.channel | % {$_.item} | 
select @{N="pubdate";E={([datetime]$_.pubdate).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")}},title
```

Comment: Nice, though note that the `[datetime]` cast, when given a UTC (GMT) timestamp string, results in _local_ time, which may or may not be EST.

Answer (score 1):

Solution

```
$url = "http://feeds.marketwatch.com/marketwatch/marketpulse"
[xml]$xml = (new-object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString($url)
$xml.rss.channel | Foreach {$_.item} | select @{N="pubdate";E={[System.TimeZoneInfo]::ConvertTimeBySystemTimeZoneId([datetime]$_.pubdate, 'Eastern Standard Time').ToString("ddd MMM d HH:mm:ss")}},title
```

Answer (score -1):

No need to convert.  Just make sure you read the date as a string from xml and convert to DateTime.  Try following :

```
using assembly System.Xml.Linq

$uri = 'http://feeds.marketwatch.com/marketwatch/marketpulse'
$doc = [System.Xml.Linq.XDocument]::Load($uri)
$items = $doc.Descendants("item")

$table =  [System.Collections.ArrayList]@()

foreach($item in $items)
{
   $title = $item.Element('title').Value
   $link = $item.Element('link').Value
   $description = $item.Element('description').Value
   $pubDate = [DateTime]$item.Element('pubDate').Value
   $guid = $item.Element('guid').Value

   $newRow = [psobject]@{
      'Title'=$Title
      'Link'=$link
      'Description'=$description
      'Pub Date'=$pubDate
      'guid'=$guid
   }
   $table.Add($newRow) | out-null
}
$table | Format-Table
```